# Xstate: different actions and guards leading to same state

Tags: statechart, xstate

I'm writing a state chart with the xstate library.

The statechart represents a medium complex UI.

I've several parallel states, but for this questions let's take into account only two:

`SelectionStatus`, which represents the select item(s), differentiating between substates `SelectedNone`, `SelectedOne`, `SelectedMany`.

`Operation`, which represents current operation in progress. It has a substate named `Idle` (among some others, of course).

There're some events which trigger actions that loop back to `Idle` substate, without going to another State. Let's think of them as immediate actions, for example a `removeSelected` action which just deletes the selected item(s) (and there's the point of the question).

I'm adding conditions to event `removeSelected` to perform different actions if the selection is limited to a single item (a node in a tree actually) or many (a branch of a tree).

The syntax of xstate to describe actions and conditions for an event would then be:

```
removeSelected: {
    Idle: {
         cond: isSelectedOneGuard,
         actions: ['removeOne']
    },
    Idle: {
         cond: isSelectedManyGuard,
         actions: ['removeMany']
    }
}
```

Problem is that I'm writing two `Idle` keys at same object nesting level, which isn't valid.

I've considered restructuring the statechart to have two branches of operations as substates of the selection ones but it seems a cure far worse than the problem.

I've also considered using intermediate dummy states like `RemovingOne` and `RemovingMany` which would simply trigger a transition back to `Idle`, but I'm not so satisfied with it.

I could solve this issue by removing the guard condition, do the test in the a generic `removeOneOrMany` action handler, but I would then loose the info about the different handling in the statechart.

Anybody had a similar problem and can provide some suggestion about this?

(Note: This is referring to current version of xstate, which is 3.1.1, 3.2 is almost there and I don't know if it could permit to handle this case more easily)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the current syntax (3.1), you can put the different "candidate transitions" in an array:

```
removeSelected: [
  {
    target: 'Idle',
    cond: isSelectedOneGuard,
    actions: ['removeOne']
  },
  {
    target: 'Idle',
    cond: isSelectedManyGuard,
    actions: ['removeMany']
  }
]
```